# Can't find the client download for SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, client

I need the SQL Server Management Studio client so I can use it to access a 2014 instance but am having a hard time finding it via Google. Where would I find only the client instead of the whole SSMS download? Any ideas on where to find it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "only the client" - you need to download the entire SSMS installation program.

Answer (score 6):

Highly recommend to use latest SSMS.

You can download the latest version of SSMS  from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Previous versions are https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238488.aspx